# Mathematica copies extra characters at the end of text blocks

Tags: warning-messages, copy-as

This is something I've been noticing for some time, but I haven't found any mention of this online, so I'd like to know if it's been seen before, if it is a (known?) bug, and whether there exist workarounds. Mathematica (I've observed this in v10.0.0 and v9.0.1 over Ubuntu 14.04) tends to add extra characters at the tail end of copied text blocks, like

```
Integrate[Erf[a + b*x]/E^(p*x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]%@ð¿1¸7=&å -¾å0
```

where the `%@ð¿1¸7=&å -¾å0` (which typically starts with several invisible characters) gets tacked on to the end. To illustrate:

[image]

The length of the added text roughly increases with the length of the copied text, though the neither the added text nor its length are consistent. Here are two addenda from immediate but separate copy-pastes of some longer text:

```
ð¿Û!¸7=&å`  Ð34P#è8`À8@Ã`x88bSeh1`vg=&E=1Oâ0K   1Why the Coloring?...±Ð34òæ8`À8@Ã

ÐAAä(Empty)@pPåÊAscrollbar_groove10000000000000000000000092000000200000000100000017000000-addpage¸7=&å¸7=&åH8=&å088=&å1÷î ò'1p®1Àn0
```

It is mostly gibberish but you do see some commands and context names in there.

So: what is this text, and can one stop it appearing?

---

> **Edit**: I can no longer reproduce this after updating to version 10.0.1.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior in Mathematica 9.0.1 on Windows 8.1.